# Behavioral current sink in ltspice

Tags: sensor, ltspice, load

In order to simulate a wireless sensor in ltspice, i need to model a load which draws 25mA current for 1sec every 10 min. Rest of the time it draw 40uA. Is there any way to do that?. I tried behavioral modelling but there are only behavioral sources. Instead of drawing 25mA its generating 25mA

Comment: A current source with a negative sign is a current sink, does that meet your requirements? While I have not used Ltspice, in other simulators I have used a voltage controlled current source like this hooked up to an offset clock source, minimum voltage is the idle, max is active, and you tweak the duty cycle for the on time

Comment: @Reroute is there any simple circuit in which i can test whether this works before i connect this to a complex circuit? Initially i though i can keep a series resistance say 10 ohm in series with a 5v source and keep the current source in parallel to divert 25mA from the 500mA. But since the voltage across the resistance is 5v it will draw 500mA. Any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: I do not follow the specifics of what your trying to do with the voltage source, as to testing my thoughts, create a 2 lead voltage source, put a voltage controlled current source in parrellel with the voltage source and look at the direction of the current?

Comment: @Reroute my doubt is instead of drawing current wont the current source generate the current specified? So how can it be used to model the required load?

Comment: If you have a current source with -1A. Which way do you suspect the current will flow? In my past experience it made it sink current. Much like a voltage source with -1V i would expect it to then ve a negative voltage

Comment: @Reroute Thanks its working. I used a opamp inverting amplifier and kept a current source at the inverting terminal. There is a reduction in the amount of current in the feedback resistance by an amount equal to that specified by current source.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of simulation, just add a current source with `PULSE 40u 25m 600 1m 1m 1 600`. The delay ensures it starts with no load, can be set to any value. The pulse width is not exactly `1 s`, the precise value would be `999 ms`. And if you are concerned about drawing current when there's no output, just add the flag `load` after the expression. From the manual:

> If the source is flagged as a load, the source is forced to be dissipative, that is, the current goes to zero if the voltage between nodes n+ and n- goes to zero. The purpose of this option is to model a current load on a power supply that doesn't draw current if the output voltage is zero. When flagged as a load, the current source starts to deviate from a constant current when the voltage across it drops to 0.5V. The impedance eventually drops to a resistance equal to .25Ω/amp times the value of the current source.

Or you can add a behavioural source with whatever expression you want. Versatility is their game. For example, if `V(out)` is the output voltage, add a reference voltage source with the same settings as the `PULSE()` current above, label the node `ref`, and use `I=u(V(out))*v(ref)` as the expression. This will only draw the required current while `V(out)>=0`.

Or concoct your own behavioural load, as the comments mentioned.